# woocommerce повторно выслать письмо о регистрации

Tags: woocommerce

Как выслать пользователю повторно письмо о регистрации с ссылкой о подтверждении внутри

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php`

`<p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', '<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to manage your wishlist and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) . '">' . wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) . '</a>'  ); ?></p>`

Comment: В данном случае , <а> будет кликабельная